# How did $\exp(sl_{-1})$ mapped $z$ to $z-s$?

Tags: conformal-field-theory

For the generator $l_{n=-1}=-z^{n+1}\partial_z$ in 2 D conformal field theory,
how did $\exp(sl_{-1})$ mapped $z$ to $z-s$?

$\exp(sl_{-1}) = \exp(s(-\partial_z)) = \exp(-s\partial_z)$
The claim was that this mapped $z\in\mathbb{C}$ to $z-s$.

I wasn't sure how the exponential map through the generator completed the transformation.

Comment: Did you expand $\exp$ in its power series?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yeah, but I'm not quite sure what if what I thought was correct: if $s$(fixed) and thus commute with $z$, then $\exp(sl_{-1})=1-s\partial_z$. Also, does those map left multiple to $z$ itself? even if it does, what about the $-s\partial_z (z\partial_z)$ term?